# In Elixir, are there efficiency reasons between each case structure?

Tags: elixir

In Elixir, are there runtime or compile-time efficiency reasons to use cond over case; case over if/else; and unless over an if statement with negated condition?

Partial answer:

- if/else: Only handles two cases.
- cond: Switches based on boolean conditions.
- case: Switches based on pattern matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `case/2` and `cond/1` are special forms that are expanded by the compiler and delegated to [`expand_case/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.12.3/lib/elixir/src/elixir_clauses.erl#L102) and [`expand_cond/3`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.12.3/lib/elixir/src/elixir_clauses.erl#L120) respectively, which are basically the exact same fold (reduce) by `expand_clauses/5`.

[`if/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Kernel.html#if/2) is a bare [elixir](/questions/tagged/elixir) macro, which is expanded to [`case/2`](https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir/blob/v1.12.3/lib/elixir/lib/kernel.ex#L3531-L3548) during compilation stage.

That said, no, there is no significant difference, besides convenience.

Comment: I see. So these structures just exist to provide concise syntax.

Comment: `case/2` might be faster than `cond/1` because of pattern-matching, in `cond/1` one might call heavy functions checking conditions.